# Min-cut and Min-$k$-cuts

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Given an undirected weighted graph $G= \langle V,E \rangle$, the min-cut algorithm is polynomial and cuts the graph to at least 2 connected components such that the sum of the weights of the edges removed is minimal.

Now min-$k$-cut asks the same thing but the result is at least $k$ connected components, this is NP complete problem!

My question is it seems intuitive to try to implement the min-cut algorithm at most $k$ times achieve at least $k$ connected components while with every new cut we choose the component that gives the least sum of weights at each step (basically greedy algorithm), so why does this not work? could you give a counter-example where the min-$k$-cut is less than $k$ iterations of min-cut?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a situation where your strategy does not work optimally even when $k=3$. Imagine that the shaded circles are very large complete graphs:

[image]

The greedy strategy will first cut the $3$ edges on the left. Then, the left component is just a large clique (with no small cuts) and the right component has three $4$-edge cuts. If we choose any one of these, we'll separate the graph into $3$ components by deleting $7$ edges.

However, deleting all $6$ edges between the middle clique and the two cliques on the right will also create $3$ components, and it is more efficient.

Comment: (I suppose if I had read the question carefully and seen "weighted", I would have given the same construction where each clique is a single vertex and there are edges of weight $3, 2, 2, 2$ between them in the same pattern.)